# How to dismiss PopViewController for another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using ashleymills/Reachability to check if user is connected to the internet and if not I want to show a popup and if there was an internet connection I want the popup to disappear.
the first part was easy and I was able to do , but I couldn't dismiss the popup when there is internet connection

The main view:

```
 func checkConnection() {
        let VC = self.getStoryBoard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "checkConnection") as! checkConnection
        VC.checkConnectivity = self
        self.showPopUp(VC, parent: self)
    }
       func isConnect(){
     let VC = self.getStoryBoard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "checkConnection") as! checkConnection
    VC.checknotConnectivity = self
    VC.dismissVC()
}

    @objc func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {
        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
        switch reachability.connection {
        case .wifi:
           isConnect()
        case .cellular:
            isConnect()
        case .none:
         checkConnection()
        }
    }
```

the popup view

```
var checkConnectivity : checkConnectivity?
 func dismissVC() {
       // self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        print("dismissVC")
    }

protocol checkConnectivity {
    func isConnect()
    func checkConnection()
}
```

I could see the print in the debugger  which means my code is being read , but does not dismiss.

Comment: What does this line mean _but the second I could dismiss the popup when there is internet connection_ ? And about your **Pop up**, is it just a `UIAlertController` or your custom made **Pop up** using `UIView` ?

Comment: it is wired, because you are saying it is printing "dismissVC" !! can you provide us more information ?

Comment: first sorry I was trying to see I can not dissmiss the popup when there is internet connection and no it,is not UIAlertController I will share my pop code for you to see it and for more info my isConnect()  checkConnection() are protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're initialising a controller in **checkConnection** method and popping up but in **isConnect** method you're again initialising the controller which is making a different instance of same controller and hence the previously initialised controller is not getting dismissed.

Try making the controller in checkConnection method as global and dismiss that controller in **isConnect** method